# External properties not loaded in Cucumber-JVM

Tags: spring, maven, cucumber, integration-testing, cucumber-jvm

I am facing the following issue: I have the following java config classes for my BDD suite - the testrunner and the main configuration class which defines PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@ContextConfiguration("Config.class")
class TestRunner {}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value ="com.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

}

In my stepDefs file I am trying to access a property from the *.properties file and it is not being picked up.

```
public class TestStepdefs {

@Value("${property}")
public String property;

@Given("^Test$")
public void test() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(property);
}
}
```

I mention that in the pom file i have included the `cucumber-spring` dependency.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Try injecting the environment and then looking at what's in there in debug to see if the properties are there in your environment.

Comment: All of my @ContextConfigurations look like this: @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/cucumber-context.xml"})

Comment: @TheRick3t did you get solution for this issue? I am facing similar issue where in my ATDD cucumber based step definition is not able to resolve the property.

Comment: @Ekanath, I remember this was an issue with the multi module structure of my project and how it was inheriting my configuration structure.